# Sharing a data disk/adding persistent storage to a swarm cluster in azure container service

Tags: azure-container-service

I wanted to share some data to every worker in a swarm cluster.what are the possible methods to do the same.The swarm was created from docker cloud with azure integration.

Can I attach a single data disk to all worker VM's in an azure swarm cluster?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please go through this guide. Your question will be flagged as it is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

adding a single datadisk to all worker VM's is not possible. As Azure is not able to provide a 'shared disk' facility. The only things which comes close to it is the usage of Azure Files see herr --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-how-to-use-files-linux
for further details